# Open Play Framework application in Cloud9 IDE browser

Tags: playframework, cloud9-ide, typesafe-activator

My Play Framework (Typesafe Activator) application is running in Cloud9.  I notice that in [Cloud9's documentation](https://c9.io/site/blog/2013/05/can-i-use-cloud9-to-do-x), it says ports are free above 16000 and local applications must be bound to the IP in the variable `$IP`.  I've got my application running on `$IP` and port 16002 but I can't seem to pull it up in the Cloud9 web browser.  I've tried the `<default_workspace_URL> + :16002` but no luck.  (Haha - and yes, even though they say it doesn't work, I tried localhost:16002...  No luck.  As expected.)

Just trying to get the Cloud9 browser pointed to the application.

Answer (score 0):

We're currently working on improving our documentation for Cloud9, which is somewhat outdated after we launched the recent version. One update on how to run certain apps can be found here: https://docs.c9.io/run_an_application.html#pre-view-your-application, and we're also starting to write documentation for popular frameworks like Meteor: https://docs.c9.io/frameworks_meteor.html.

The documentation repo is open source, so if you find a way to make your framework run on Cloud9, Pull Requests are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Your application must be bound to $IP and $PORT. The documentation states that $PORT is exposed to the outside.
In my experiments of running Activator on Cloud9, I use : `-Dhttp.address=$IP` and     `-Dhttp.port=$PORT`

Then to find the url you should use, try to "Preview with web server" and pick the url in the browser bar.
The format of the url seems to change with Cloud9 versions. In my case it's in the form : `appname-c9-username.c9.io`

Hope it helps.